# Recurring payment with stripe with varying amount

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am working on a project where the subscriber can limit his subscription on monthly basis.

**As an example below**

```
Lets say i have 5 products A - Euro 40 ,B - Euro 40, C - Euro 40, D- Euro 40,E - Euro 40

Month 1 - A + B + C + D -> First order. I am using stripe ideal to generate the payment for 4 products. Total Euro 160

Month 2 - Subscriber cancels product D subscription. So now the recursive payment must work only for the price of A+B+C. So now the total comes Euro 120

Month 3 - Subscriber cancels product C subscription. So now the recursive payment must work only for the price of A+B. So now the total comes Euro 80

Month 4 - Subscriber cancels product A + B subscription. So the subscription should be cancelled.
```

Work done till now:

The stripe ideal is only one time payment. In this case, i can use SEPA but will get the update 14-16 working days.
https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal/recurring

I am using wordpress and initiating the ideal payment programatically (not using plugin) using Stripe PHP library.

What is the alternative i can go for iDEAL?

Is it possible, if i collect the card details of the customer and charge the card on recurring basis without user authorization.

Hope i made my question clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm admittedly not particularly learned in this world, but Stripe does have some guidance here:

https://stripe.com/docs/sources/ideal/recurring

Basically, you have to turn it into a SEPA Direct Debit source, then every month inform your customer of what they're going to owe.  Hopefully that's helpful!